# What boolean value does an assignment operation implicitly evaluate to in C?

Tags: c++, c, conditional-statements

I stumbled across this code recently:

```
void strcat( char* dest, char* src )
{
     while (*dest) dest++;
     while (*dest++ = *src++);
}
```

Where it looks like the `*dest++ = *src++` operation is being used as a condition for the while loop. How is this assignment operation converted to boolean? I'm having a hard time understanding it.

Furthermore, is the same syntax valid in C++?

Comment: I would like to see an answer cover how/when the `++` operator is applied as well (or how it can be ignored for sake of discussing the conditional/assignment stuff), just in quick passing, as it is sort of cryptic. Also, don't forget the the question asks if C++ has the same rules here.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In C, a non-zero value in a logical statement counts as a *true*, zero as *false*.

And the result of any assignment statement is the value of the left operand after the assignment.

And so in the second loop, if the value assigned is `0`, the result of the condition is *false*. In the first loop, if the value of the pointed-to variable *itself* is `0`, the condition is *false*.

This syntax is also valid in C++.

Comment: For completeness - the second loop above will copy all characters up to and including a \0.

Comment: The result of the assignment operation is the value of the left operand and not the value of the right operand; this is not the same and there is a subtle difference between the two.

Comment: @pb2q "..and automatic conversion between bool and integral values" -- So is there an implicit/automatic conversion here before the value is used in the conditional?

Comment: -1 for stating that C++ had a proper `bool` type and C hadn't. C has `_Bool` since C99, and the macros `bool`, `false` and `true` in `"stdbool.h"`.

Comment: @pst _So is there an implicit/automatic conversion here before the value is used in the conditional_ -- I believe that it is so. From _6.4/4 Selection Statements_: _The value of a condition that is an expression is the value of the expression, contextually converted to bool for statements other than switch;_. And also: _6.4/2_: _The rules for conditions apply both to selection-statements and to the for and while statements_. But I've removed the bit about `bool` from the answer for now, it does need work.

Answer (score 2):

> What boolean value does an assignment operation implicitly evaluate to in C?

An assignment operation evaluates to the variable being assigned (left hand side):

```
int i = 0;
int j = (i = i+5); // j == 5 | (i = i+5) assigns 5, then evaluates to i
```

Now, when used as a condition, an integral value evaluates to *true* when it is non-zero or to *false* if it is zero.

Comment: upvote this one too, because I suspect the real question is not about boolean, but about the value of the assignment operation result.

Comment: “An assignment operation evaluates to the value that was assigned” No it doesn't, it evaluates to the value of the variable after the assignment. Try `unsigned char ch; printf("%d", (ch = 300));`

Comment: @PascalCuoq: I might not have use the proper wording. The assignment expression is an lvalue expression that refers to the left hand side of the assignment (i.e. it evaluates to the variable being assigned, which can then undertake an lvalue-to-rvalue conversion to yield the stored value)

Answer (score 0):

An expression that evaluates to 0 is false.
An expression that evaluates to non-zero is true.

When *dest equal 0, the first while loop will terminate.

Similarly with the second.

Comment: Please consider reading the question next time. I was asking precisely how an assignment operation evaluates to non-zero.